# Typical exercises for exam in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to get fit for my exam in complex analysis and search for some typical exercises, proofs that are doable in 90 mins. I want to prepare me well for the exam. To be more explicit:

1. Proofs about the theorem of Goursat or Cauchy's integral theorem. For example: Something one need to devide the domain into several triangular parts and then say it's zero.
2. Proofs with the identity principle.
3. Some exercises where I can use Liouville's theorem or the Maximum principle.

Maybe somebody knows some exercises and solutions in PDF or Book format or can give me some basic exercises to one of these or other topics in compl. analy.

Comment: There's always the Schaum's Outline of complex analysis.

Comment: One may also try Bak and Newman.

Comment: See the Berkeley problem book in mathematics..  Complex analysis section. They are a bit tough but very good!